# Error while connecting to database in code-first Entity Framework

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am getting following error message when context is trying to connect to database using code-first approach of Entity Framework

> System.Data.Entity.DbContext' does not contain a definition for 'System' and no extension method 'System' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Code:

```
public class Context : DbContext, IDisposable
{
    public Context() : base("EcommConnectionString")
    {
    }

    public List<Entities.RLI_State> States { get; set; }
    public List<Entities.RLI_Product> Products { get; set; }
    public List<Entities.RLI_StateProduct_List> StateProductList { get; set; }
}
```

This is how my connection string defined in `web.config`:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="EcommConnectionString" 
         value="data source=localhost;initial catalog=tempdb;integrated security=SSPI" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: First of all, `DbContext` already imlpements `IDisposable` so you don't need that. Secondly your `List<>` properties should probably by `DbSet<>` instead.

Comment: Also, where are you getting this error? Can you show that code? It looks like you have some code somewhere saying `context.System()` which is obviously not correct.

Comment: Thanks David , after doing those two changes that error has gone but some new error

Comment: I can  figured out that error . I can mark your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here.

Firstly, DbContext already imlpements IDisposable so you don't need that. It's not a problem having it there, but it is redundant.

Secondly your `List<>` properties should be using `DbSet<>` instead:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context() : base("EcommConnectionString")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Entities.RLI_State> States { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Entities.RLI_Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Entities.RLI_StateProduct_List> StateProductList { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, as @marc_s mentioned, the connection string in your web.config should be in the `<connectionStrings>` element, not in `<appSettings>`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="EcommConnectionString" 
         connectionString="data source=localhost;initial catalog=tempdb;integrated security=SSPI" />
</connectionStrings>
```